# Silverlight 4 and Youtube flash player

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, youtube, embed

I'm trying to make a small silverlight application but i became across a problem, playing videos from youtube.
I tried a method with a html conteiner to embed the youtube flash player, but with this method i need to activate the option windowsless, and thats is not a good ideia for my web site.
If anyone have a good ideia,I'm glad to hear

thanks
BasicSide

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight actually supports the `H.264` format so you can play videos directly within your application.

There's a tutorial here that outlines how to do this:

http://www.uxpassion.com/2009/08/silverlight-tutorial-play-hd-youtube-videos-silverlight/